# Какаовий чи виготовлений з какао?

Tags: вживання-слів, стилістика

Під час пошуку рецептів зустрічала різні варіанти формулювання задля вказівки на використання какао.

На сайті [depositphotos](https://ua.depositphotos.com/165335534/stock-photo-sweet-chocolate-made-of-cocoa.html) бачу таке:

> Солодкий шоколад, **виготовлений з какао**.

Однак помітним є й використання  слова "какаовий". Навіть у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) знайшла:

> Дівчина **какаова**

Отож цікавить використання власне другого варіанту. Чи нормативно (літературно) використовувати слово ***"какаовий"***, чи все ж варто замінювати на ***"виготовлений з какао"***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово **какаовий** можна використовувати, оскільки знаходимо його у [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/kakaovyj):

> **КАКА́ОВИЙ,** а, е. Прикм. до какао.

Також знаходимо це слово в [Орфографічному словнику](//slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9) та у [Словнику лемківської говірки](//ukrainian_lemko.academic.ru/5066/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9).
Отже, вживання слова **какаовий** є нормативним.

Comment: Наводити словник лемків јак доказ нормативности — дешчо не дуже доречно, а загалом все так.

Comment: Хоч _какаовий_ мені трішки ріже слух і нечастно вживається, але так — воно є в словниках (причому без усіляких позначок про обмеженість уживання).